# win7 keyboard layout change from logon screen

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, login-screen

I am having a nightmare right now, which is I'm stuck on logon screen of windows 7 professional. My password includes turkish characters and the keyboard layout changed somehow to english. And on logon screen I can't seem to find anywhere to change the keyboard layout. Hence I cannot logon to my windows, can't use my pc.

What should I do?

Comment: oh god, my father just told me the same thing happened to him. I need to fix this to him and he is in another continent. It's too bad that the solution is that complicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I ended up resetting my password with a third party software. [Here](http://www.muratyazici.com/windows-7-sifre-sifirlama-resimli-anlatim.html) is the link that I found, even though it is in Turkish I guess it is still really helpful. And here is the direct download [link](http://muratyazici.com/wp-content/yazilar/win7passwd/win7passwd-reset.rar).

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck on the login screen on Windows Server 2003 while my keyboard language was accidentally changed to one that I don't have my password set in.

The solution was to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to toggle between the keyboard languages.

Comment: In the upper left of the screen, you can see which keyboard language is currently selected.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In the end I discovered that to change a keyboard layout, you can use the (left) CTRL-SHIFT combination. 
To see which layout it is set to, I use the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: ALT-SHIFT, not CTRL-SHIFT, and it can be either left or right -- this is on Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 2):

In some versions of Windows you have the option to choose keyboard language right on the login screen, in the upper left corner of the screen. In your situation, you would have seen the letters EN inscribed in a square. If you click on it, a dropdown appears and you are able to choose the desired language.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can suggest is quickly looking up the [Alt+xxx](http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html) values for the characters to at least get you in the system. Once you have done that, you can then use the `Control Panel` method mentioned by @MOPTOH

Comment: In fact, for languages, you might find it easier to find here: http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html

Comment: I was very hopeful about this solution, but didn't work :/

Comment: Are you using the Numpad or the numbers at the top of the keyboard? Also, if you have not used this method before, you need to ensure that you are holding down `Alt` until you have pressed all the numbers required (so you cant do Alt+1, Alt+2, Alt+8 to get Ç). If you are on a laptop and do not have a defined Numpad, often you will still have a NumLock key and when pressed, the NumPad buttons are mapped on the main keyboard

Comment: If you still have troubles, RegEdit may be a possibility. Will edit my answer to add this option in a minute (need to remember where these are in registry)

Comment: @MOPTOH has the better option though rather than editing the registry. Changing the password is probably the safer way to go

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities depend on the version of Windows and possibly on how it's configured.

On my Windows 7 Enterprise at work, I don't have a way to change the keyboard layout, but there is a button at the bottom left to enable accessibility features. Select "On-Screen Keyboard", then hunt and peck. Depending on the layout you're stuck with, some characters may require you to first press "[AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)" (some languages use a different name) at the right of the space bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem, not able to login in window 7 because accidentally change language.my language show in urdu but i make password in English language. So please how can i login after change my language from urdu to english.please guide