# Password for Windows in language which is not available

Tags: windows-7, passwords, input-languages

My Password to enter Windows is in Greek, but in the logon Screen the Greek language is not supported.

The same thing happened with another person in the ([Forum](https://superuser.com/questions/706207/win7-keyboard-layout-change-from-logon-screen)), but the answers cannot help me... First I don't have a recovery disk. Second, on the end, he solves the issue with a solution is on a [Website](http://www.muratyazici.com/windows-7-sifre-sifirlama-resimli-anlatim.html) written in Turkish, which I don't speak.

Please, can somebody somehow help me?

This is really a Problem which Microsoft should have not allowed to happen.

---

### Edit #1

Issues occurs even if I have a CD.

Because until the command line I can make it, even without CD, but the language which I have to write is Greek, and the commands which I have to type are in English.

1. I turn on the Computer;
2. I press F8;
3. I choose "Repair Computer";
4. System asks for an input language;

   4.1. I choose greek.
5. System asks for Username and Password. In Username, there are 2 options:

   5.1. My Administrator Account, which has a Password in Greek language;

   5.2. The second option is an accound I see first time - HomeGroupUser$ - which I dont know the Password.
6. I choose my account and I put my password (in greek);
7. Now I have some more options, but the language I can write is greek... and that's the Problem.

Comment: Change the password outside of Windows to a password in another language.  You won't be able to solve this without a recovery disk, so get yourself on, they are easy enough to find.

Comment: You could try the `net user hack` or `NT Offline Registry & Password editor` - both of which are fairly complicated but will get the job done if you can boot to a LiveCD or USB

Comment: See: [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=tr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muratyazici.com%2Fwindows-7-sifre-sifirlama-resimli-anlatim.html translates the turkish pretty well.

Comment: I didn't understand well what is the issue. Please, say us how do you set password in Greek and why your logon screen is not in Greek. And if you explain it with pictures, it would be better.

Comment: ok, i got a repair disc which i alone made from another Computer. i managed to get to the Command Prompt and write in english, but the drive which i see is X: and specificaly ist like this   X:\windows\system32>       the Problem is also that the command line Ends with >

Comment: `X:\windows\system32>` is normal. It is just the prompt showing the drive and current directory. `>` is the end of the prompt. You can just type the commands here that you need to enter. See answer [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/a/247953) for instructions.

Comment: If you did not like `>`, you would type `prompt %cd% :) ` and then enter :)

Comment: @Krisbee, give us some feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understand, you cannot login because OS does not allow you to enter your password in Greek, where you use special characters...

If so, try that:

### Solution 1: Change language and keyboard (the noob way)

1. On top left of your logon screen, there are two buttons. One of them has the language options and the second has the keyboard options. Press them and try to find your keyboard configuration there.
2. If successfull, use the same way to enter the computer when you reboot it.

### Solution 2: Input special characters with alt+num keys (the hack way)

1. Regardless of your computer language and keyboard configuration on Windows, you can enter special characters through holding `alt` key and pressing 4 digits on your numeric keys (those ones on the right side of your keyboard). If your keyboard do not have that numeric keys (but only those ones above alphabet keys), provide one to follow next steps. You will need access to another computer with Windows or with ant OS but with internet to discover codes for each character of your password;
2. On a computer with Windows installed, press WinKey+R (or Start Menu > Execute...), type `charmap` and then press enter. Note: the codes here is in hexadecimal;
3. If you do not have another computer with Windows use any device that can navigate internet and search for ASCII codes;
4. Then with step 2 or 3 done, search for characters of your password and the code in decimal (if you have them in hexadecimal, use Windows `calc` to convert). For instance "ΑΧΙα" -> codes in hexadecimal: 80, 95, 88, 98 -> codes in decimal: 128, 149, 136, 152;
5. So, with decimal codes, use on the "bad computer" `Alt+XXXX` to type each character, where `XXXX`is the code with 4 digits using numeric keys. Note that all characters have less than 4 digits, so complete with left zeros. For instance, to enter "ΑΧΙα", you have to do following combo: `Alt+0128`, `Alt+0149`, `Alt+0136`, `Alt+0152`.
6. After entering the system, change your password to something more global :)

### Solution 3: Remote desktop connection (another hacker way)

1. Well, if you know the name of tour "bad computer" on the network and if you have another computer with Windows on the same network, why not to use Remote Desktop Connection on the other computer to access the bad one? Windows use default configuration to allow it, but you would have some issue if you enabled more protection... But try it;
2. With a "good computer" (another computer were you can use Greek) on the same network, on Windows Explorer, press Network on left panel and searcho for your "bad computer" and take note of its name;
3. Start Menu > Accessories > Remote Desktop Conection and use the name of your computer. If successfull, you can use see the bad computer screen and use the keyboard of the good computer. Using that way, you can use Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v to copy and paste your password in case of you cannot type it in the keyboard, but "compose" it in charmap.